# Access textbox from another method or Async

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, asynchronous

I'm somewhat new to C# and I'm having some issues retrieving a `textbox` value in an asynchronous method. I the thread to retrieve the text input in the UI and use it in the code. VS 2010 accepts my code but when I start to debug it gives me the following exception
`Invalid cross-thread access`. Ideas? Am I missing something?

```
public void Response_Completed(IAsyncResult result)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);

    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        JObject rootObject = JObject.Load(new JsonTextReader(streamReader));

        string tracknum = trackid.Text; // Invalid cross-thread access exception
        string source = rootObject[tracknum]["source"].ToString();

        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            //removed
        });
    }
}
```

Note: I'm attempting to do this on the Windows Phone 7 Platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to get textbox value on UI thread, instead of other threads. [Invoke method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) executes the specified delegate on the UI thread:

```
string tracknum = (string)trackid.Invoke(new Func<string>(() => trackid.Text));
```

**Edit:**

On Windows Phone:

```
string tracknum = string.Empty;
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
   {
       tracknum = trackid.Text;
       string source = rootObject[tracknum]["source"].ToString();
   });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but will this work on Windows Phone 7? I tried this, but it's not working giving a 'System.Controls.Textbox' does not contain a definition for 'Invoke?

Comment: @ForeverLearning: Well, don't actually know you run on Window Phone 7, you should tag it.

Comment: Sorry, added now. Thankyou for your input though!

Comment: Thankyou! the BeginInvoke was the key for the UI working in ASync on Windows Phone! Trivially, I did have a null reference exception when it was just the tracknum inside the BeginInvoke. (Edited the piece of code to reflect working code)

Once again, thankyou for your time and effor, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You'll receive such exception because you have tried to access an object from a different thread than that it was created on (tried to access the thread asynchronously)

To get around this, we'll need to execute a delegate on the thread that owns the control's underlying window handle. In such cases, we may use `Invoke(Delegate method)`

**Example**

```
public void Response_Completed(IAsyncResult result)
{
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
         HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
         HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);
         using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
         {
            JObject rootObject = JObject.Load(new JsonTextReader(streamReader));
            string tracknum = trackid.Text; // Invalid cross-thread access exception
            string source = rootObject[tracknum]["source"].ToString();
         }
    });
}
```

`MethodInvoker` provides a simple delegate that is used to invoke a method with a void parameter list. This delegate can be used when making calls to a control's `Invoke` method, or when you need a simple delegate but do not want to define one yourself.

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: Thankyou for the reply :) I'm currently writing this for a Windows Phone application (learning Async), it seems that I can't invoke delegates asynchronously?

Comment: @ForeverLearning Oh, sorry about that. I'm glad you had your issue resolved. Have a great day! :)